# Split Swift package into two (or more) distinct imports

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, swift-package

I am diving into dependency management with SPM, here is my `Package.swift`

```
let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MyPackage",
            targets: ["MyPackage"]),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyPackage",
            path: "Sources") // it targets a whole folder 
    ]
)
```

The thing is that, since I am building a personal Package which gathers a lot of different utility methods and classes that are not interdependent, I want to be able to split it into different "modules" or "imports".

For instance, I have 2 subfolders in `Sources`: `Widgets` and `Networking`. The first one gathers all my UIView / UIControls widgets, and in the second one a bundle of protocols that helps me building API class.

I want to be able to split those two into two imports, considering that I sometime don't need one or the other in my projects. making it feasible to write `import MyPackageNetworking` and `import MyPackageWidgets`

I tried:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v14)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MyPackage",
            targets: ["MyPackageNewtorking", "MyPackageWidgets"]),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyPackageNewtorking",
            path: "Sources/Newtorking"),
        .target(
            name: "MyPackageWidgets",
            path: "Sources/Widgets")
    ]
)
```

but no luck on this side. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: SDWebImage does it for instance, maybe by checking its Package.swift: https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/blob/master/Package.swift

Comment: hmm understood I have to split the target *and* the products ! Thanks a lot @Larme

Comment: I didn’t use path for my target and instead named the subfolders the same as the target